# Getting PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.. Exception when trying to connect SQL SERVER with Pyspark locally

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, pkix

I am trying to connect to locally installed sql-server-2017 with pyspark. My intend is to create Df from it.

While doing so, I am getting the error as:-

`An error occurred while calling o51.load. : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:fe719377-52ee-412f-9080-e97f5ae480db  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3680)    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:2113)    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3204)    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2833)    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2671)  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1640)  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:936)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProvider$.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:77)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcUtils.scala:64)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.getQueryOutputSchema(JDBCRDD.scala:62)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:57)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:239)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:36)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:350)  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)     at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target  at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)   at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)   at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)   at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:652)     at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:471)    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:367)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376)     at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:479)    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:457)    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:155)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1315)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1228)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:384)    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:2021)    ... 30 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)     at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)  at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271)    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:232)    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:109)  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$HostNameOverrideX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(IOBuffer.java:1702)  at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1255)    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:636)     ... 42 more Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target  at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)     at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)   at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)     ... 50 more`

My code is below pasted,
`import os
import sys

`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`
`sparkady = SparkSession`
`.builder`
`.master('local[*]')`
`.appName('Connection-Test')`
`.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', r'C:\Projects\pyspark\sqljdbc_10_2enu\mssql-jdbc-10.2.0.jre8.jar')`
`.config('spark.executor.extraClassPath', r'C:\Projects\pyspark\sqljdbc_10_2enu\mssql-jdbc-10.2.0.jre8.jar')`
`.getOrCreate()`

`sqlsUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;database=feederDB'`

`qryStr = """ (`
`SELECT *`
`FROM Sparkbuilder`
`) as table """`

`sparkady.read.format('jdbc')`
`.option('url',sqlsUrl)`
`.option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')`
`.option('dbtable', qryStr )`
`.option("user", "aditya")` 
`.option("password", "Tiger@90")` 
`` .load().show()` ``

I downloaded the jdbc driver for sql server from this page-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You want to format the entire block as code, not each line.

Comment: When you downloaded the JDBC driver did you read the [Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver) on the neighboring page? BREAKING CHANGE TLS encryption is enabled by default.  BREAKING CHANGE When encrypt = false but the server requires encryption, the certificate will be validated based on the trustServerCertificate connection setting.